# Determine if ElementFinder or ElementArrayFinder?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Is there an official way to determine if the input I'm receiving from a function is an `ElementFinder` (a single web element) or an `ElementArrayFinder` (a collection of web elements).

So far I've got this.

```
if (_.isFunction(elemOrElems.count)) {
    // it's an ElementArrayFinder
}
```

This seems like it's depending on an API that could easily break in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you don't want to depend on a method, how about using instanceof?

```
if(elemOrElems instanceof protractor.ElementFinder){
..
}
```